# didOutputSampleBuffer Delegate Never Gets Called (iOS / Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I am trying to keep track of the sample buffer rate of a video recording.

I have a view controller with `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and then setting the buffer output like so:

```
sessionQueue.async { [weak self] in
        if let `self` = self {
            let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

            let bufferQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "bufferRate", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent)

            let theOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
                theOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
                theOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
                theOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: bufferQueue)

            if self.session.canAddOutput(theOutput) {
                self.session.addOutput(theOutput)
                print("ADDED BUFFER OUTPUT")
            }

            if self.session.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput) {
                self.session.beginConfiguration()
                self.session.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
                self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
                if let connection = movieFileOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                    if connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported {
                        connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .auto
                    }
                }

                self.session.commitConfiguration()

                self.movieFileOutput = movieFileOutput

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    if let `self` = self {
                        self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Additionally, I have the function put into place to read the buffer:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    print("captured \(sampleBuffer)")
}
```

The problem is that when running the camera, it records correctly like it is supposed to (code not shown as it is working like normal) but the captureOutput sample buffer never gets called. What am I doing wrong? I assume it has to do with the way I am setting it up?

Comment: Your trying to use 2 outputs, try just the dataOutput first and then see if its fired

Comment: Also what are you trying to achieve using the 2 different outputs ? MovieFileOutput gives you the video as a file and dataOuput gives you the samples that essentially make up the file?

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Well to be honest, I need to make sure the video ends at an exact duration and setting timers made it always off by a few milliseconds and messing up syncing with another videos and maxduration on the capture did.. well nothing except throwing alerts and being off as well. I thought this could be more precise. Unless there's something better?

Comment: yeah dataOuput will be much more accurate but you will need to basically change your system over to use that for recording i believe

Comment: Oh really? Uh oh a re-write, exactly what I was trying to avoid! Although slightly unrelated to this post, do you know of any accurate way to track time and setting limits moviefileoutput? Timers for 4.0 seconds always gives like 4.03 or 4.10... (Sorry to detract)

Comment: well you gain other features writing in the data output manner, like exact control over quality settings, if you intend to upload it, this is probably what your gonna have to do

Comment: But you can just get the movieFileOutput.maxRecordingDuration ...

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Yes, I went back to that route except that it is even less accurate than the timer.. unfortunate there is no better way to control recording timing with finer control. You'd think 4 seconds means 4 seconds, apparently not...

Comment: 2 solutions go full data ouput and record timestamps, record roughly 4 seconds then re-cut the video to exactly 4 seconds, should only take a few seconds to cut

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the delegate signature is correct with Swift 3 syntax.

`func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`

I was using Swift 2.3 syntax and compiler did not warn me of the issue. try to type out the didOut sampleBuffer and check if XCode autocorrects the proper syntax for that delegate method.

Comment: @leowanbt14 Cool I'll check it out

Comment: This happened to me with the transition from Swift 3 -> Swift 4 as well!